# PHP page not redirecting or sending data

Tags: php

Below is my code from a posting.php document that sends it to an email - What it is currently doing is showing a white page - The status is 200 so its not a WPOD its also not sending the email and I cannot click to why.

**CODE:**

```
   <?php
        if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Place Order")
      {
          $errorMessage = "";
            if(empty($_POST['Name']))
        {
          $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot your name</li>";
         }
            if(empty($_POST['Contact']))
        {
          $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot your contact number</li>";
         }   

            if(empty($_POST['Email']))
        {
          $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot your email</li>";
         }

            if(empty($_POST['Company']))
        {
          $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot your company name</li>";
         }

            if(empty($_POST['Attending']))
        {
          $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot the number of people attending</li>";
         }

            if(empty($_POST['Function']))
        {
          $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot the function date</li>";
         }

            if(empty($_POST['FunctionDay']))
        {
          $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot the function day</li>";
         }

            if(empty($_POST['Time']))
        {
          $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot the time required</li>";
         }

            if(empty($_POST['Address']))
        {
          $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot the delivery address</li>";
         }

            if(empty($_POST['Invoice']))
        {
      $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot the invoice name</li>";
     }
        if(empty($_POST['Details']))
    {
      $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot the order details</li>";
     }

    $varName = strip_tags($_POST['Name']);
    $varContact = strip_tags($_POST['Contact']);
    $varEmail = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
    $varCompany = strip_tags($_POST['Company']);
    $varAttending = strip_tags($_POST['Attending']);
    $varFunction = strip_tags($_POST['Function']);
    $varFunctionDay = strip_tags($_POST['FunctionDay']);
    $varOrdered = strip_tags($_POST['Ordered']);
    $varTime = strip_tags($_POST['Time']);
    $varOnsite = strip_tags($_POST['Onsite']);
    $varOnsite2 = strip_tags($_POST['Onsite2']);
    $varInvoice = strip_tags($_POST['Invoice']);
    $varAddress = strip_tags($_POST['Address']);
    $varSpecial = strip_tags($_POST['Special']);
    $varDetails = strip_tags($_POST['Details']);
    $menu = strip_tags($_POST['menu']);

    $itemstr = '';
    $i=0;

    foreach($_POST['item'] as $item)
    {
        $itemstr .= "ITEM:". $item . ' Amount: '. $_POST['amount'][$i++]."<br/>";

    }

    /*$specialstr = '';
    $i=0;

    foreach($_POST['special'] as $special)
    {
        $specialstr .= "Special Needs:". $special ."<br/>";

    }

    ."<br/><strong>Special Needs:</strong><br/><br/>".  $specialstr
    */



    if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {   
        $to = "jess@jzm.co.nz";
        $subject = "Booking";
        $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"  . header("Location: http://redherringcatering.co.nz/Thankyou.html");
        $message = "\n" . "<strong>NAME:</strong>    ". $varName . "<br />" . "<br />"  . "<strong>CONTACT:</strong>     " . $varContact . "<br />" . "<br />" . "<strong>EMAIL:</strong>    ". $varEmail . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>COMPANY:</strong>     ". $varCompany . "<br />" . "<br />"  . "<strong>No. ATTENDING:</strong>    ".$varAttending . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>FUNCTION DATE:</strong>    ". $varFunction . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>FUNCTION DAY:</strong>     ". $varFunctionDay . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>DATE ORDERED:</strong>  ". $varOrdered . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>TIME REQUIRED:</strong>     ". $varTime . "<br />" . "<br />"  . "<strong>ONSITE:</strong>  ". $varOnsite . ", ". $varOnsite2 . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>INVOICE TO:</strong>     ". $varInvoice . "<br />" . "<br />" ."<strong>ADDRESS:</strong>\n". $varAddress . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>SPECIAL NEEDS:</strong>   ". $varSpecial . "<br />" . "<br />" . "<strong>ORDER DETAILS:</strong>".  $varDetails. "<br /><strong>Menu:</strong><br/><br/>".  $menu . "<br/><strong>Item Details:</strong><br/><br/>".  $itemstr ."\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);


        exit;
    }


  }
?>
```

Comment: You are not outputting anything so that would explain a white screen.

Comment: @jeroen But if you look at the if statement it has a header redirect in it

Comment: White Screen of Death usually means PHP fatal error. Try turning error reporting on `ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: I don't see any redirect in there.

Comment: It's appended to the email headers.

Comment: Oh, now I see it. You're attempting to concatenate the output of the redirect into a string?  That won't work.  Redirect should be a line all its own.

Comment: @developerwjk Was meaning header location I have been given this code to fix

Comment: Are you sure `$errorMessage` is empty?

Comment: @showdev, Doesn't matter; the error will be thrown after that check.

Comment: Header redirects do seem to work when appended to a string like that. [Example here](http://viper-7.com/lJ1dtS). But if `$errorMessage` isn't empty, nothing will happen. (Of course, as mentioned, the redirect shouldn't be done like this. But that's a different issue, in my opinion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirect works:

```
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n" . 
           "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"  . 
           header("Location: http://redherringcatering.co.nz/Thankyou.html");
```

This is not the way to redirect, you do not add a [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirect to the header of your mail, these are two completely different things.

You should remove the redirect there and put it after the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. But then only if the mail is delivered successfully:

```
if(empty($errorMessage)) 
{   
    $to = "jess@jzm.co.nz";
    $subject = "Booking";
    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n"
               . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $message = "\n" . "<strong>NAME:</strong>    ". $varName . "<br />" . "<br />"  . "<strong>CONTACT:</strong>     " . $varContact . "<br />" . "<br />" . "<strong>EMAIL:</strong>    ". $varEmail . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>COMPANY:</strong>     ". $varCompany . "<br />" . "<br />"  . "<strong>No. ATTENDING:</strong>    ".$varAttending . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>FUNCTION DATE:</strong>    ". $varFunction . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>FUNCTION DAY:</strong>     ". $varFunctionDay . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>DATE ORDERED:</strong>  ". $varOrdered . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>TIME REQUIRED:</strong>     ". $varTime . "<br />" . "<br />"  . "<strong>ONSITE:</strong>  ". $varOnsite . ", ". $varOnsite2 . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>INVOICE TO:</strong>     ". $varInvoice . "<br />" . "<br />" ."<strong>ADDRESS:</strong>\n". $varAddress . "<br />" . "<br />"  ."<strong>SPECIAL NEEDS:</strong>   ". $varSpecial . "<br />" . "<br />" . "<strong>ORDER DETAILS:</strong>".  $varDetails. "<br /><strong>Menu:</strong><br/><br/>".  $menu . "<br/><strong>Item Details:</strong><br/><br/>".  $itemstr ."\n";

    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if ($result)
    {
        header("Location: http://redherringcatering.co.nz/Thankyou.html");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
      // some error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the $errorMessage is giving me string(37) "
You forgot the order details
"

I think this should be in the else am I correct but im unsure what to replace the if empty with

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Obviously you need to add error handling to the outer `if` as well...

Comment: Correct can you do an example - I am just confusing myself

Comment: @JessMcKenzie How about echoing an unordered list with the errors?

Comment: @JessMcKenzie `echo $errorMessage;` something you're not doing. You're only assigning the variable.